# how to import into svelte-check into a project?

Tags: svelte

(Semi-beginner here)
I want to check my version of svelte.

in same folder as my package.json, I ran

```
npm i svelte-check --save-dev
npm install
```

`npm run svelte-check`   gives a error  Missing script: "svelte-check"

I see a folder called  \node_modules\svelte-check - I think i need do do another step to run it?

Answer (score 1):

`Missing script: "svelte-check"` means that the `script` that you want to run is not available !

you have to update your `package.json` file as below :

```json
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "svelte-check": "svelte-check" // add this line
        // ...
    },
    // ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "svelte-check": "..." // add this line
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "svelte-check": "^3.0.2",  was added during the npm install. 
and I added  to scripts :    "svelte-check": "svelte-check"
but when I run svelte-check, I get a different error:
The term 'svelte-check' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet....

Comment: Make sure you have no duplicate scripts section like `"scripts": {},` is declared twice or `"scripts": {},` inside `"scripts": {},` and make sure you have saved the changes inside your `package.json` file if the issue still occures try to kill your terminal an close your project then restard. should work

Comment: Ahmed, I do not see anything wrong with my package.json (see copy below)
{
  "name": "arweavejs",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "svelte-check": "svelte-check" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.54.0",
    "svelte-check": "^3.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "arweave": "1.11",
    "zod": "^3.20.2"
  }
}